# Bootstrap 5.3.0 Dropdown menu not working

Tags: javascript, dropdown, navbar, bootstrap-5, jquery-mobile-navbar

My dropdown is working as in desktop and in movile version and ipad plus it toggle and collapse.

The issues is when i press it it only show the button but it doenst shwo the dropdown list after it is ipad version even i added javascrip jquery and css.

This is my code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()
});
</script>


   <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">APIzoid</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data- target="#navbarToggleButton" aria-controls="navbarToggleButton" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button> 
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerButton">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page"  href="#">Home</a>  
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item"> 
           <a class="nav-link active" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Fitness</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
           <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Blog</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Contact</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
</nav>

<script src="jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./javascript/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: `'dropdown-toggle'` isn't a valid selector. You also don't appear to have any element with that classname or id. You've also got an unwanted space in `data- target` (which should be `data-bs-target`) and inconsistent use of `navbarToggleButton` / `navbarTogglerButton`

Comment: Here's your code with all the typos fixed and invalid parts removed ~ https://jsfiddle.net/qeb3gac4/1/